# Vim regex : Binary number

Tags: regex, vim

I want to match binary numbers in vim,

such as *0b101* , *0b111010* , or *0b110* in *0b110;*

but not *0b1013* , or *0b10* in *0b10c*

I am trying to do it like this in vim script:

```
syntax match Number "\v\W0[bB][01][01]*"
```

However, it also matches *0b101* in *0b101fa*.

Is there any way to match them correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Use the word delimiter `\<` and `\>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these commands :

```
:syntax match BinaryNb /\v<0[Bb][01]+>/
:highlight link BinaryNb Error
```

**Demo**:

[image]

Comment: I tried there commands but it doesn't work. I'm using vim 7.4.

Comment: If you are refering to highlighting, try with `:syntax on`.

Comment: It does work now, but when I put these commands in my *cpp.vim* script, it doesn't work. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the script is sourced.

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal must match byte unit. Refer to following image.

[image]